# How to write a callback for popup menu in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have four items(Types of soils) to be inserted in popup menu and the output should be integer values(porosities) displayed using a  static text. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you will be using GUIDE to create your GUI. Here is a simple code for populating a popup menu with pre-defined strings and use the selected item to change the displayed output in the static text:

1) In order to populate the popup menu, simply create a cell array of strings and set the 'String' property of the menu to that cell array:

% Create cell array

```
SoilTypes = {'Soil A' 'Soil B' 'Soil C' 'Soil D'};
```

% Set the string property of the popup menu:

```
set(handles.popupenu1,'String',SoilTypes);
```

2) Now the callback you are talking about seems to be the Selection Change callback, which might look like this:

```
function Popupmenu1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

This gets executed when the user changes the selected item in the popupmenu. Therefore, you want to get the selected item with this line:

```
get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')
```

So according the the previous cell array, you can use (among other options) a switch/case scenario in which you can do whatever stuff you want for every type of soil, such as displaying text in the static text box. You can also set directly the string in the text box like so:

```
SelectedItem = get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value') % Get the value, from 1 to 4 in your case

set(handles.text1,'String',SoilTypes{SelectedItem}); % Display the corresponding soil type
```

Hope that helps get you started!